# Python Flask SQL Alchemy Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

Just got a new laptop and cannot get a solution to run the DB migration. It works perfectly fine on another machine and also on a Ubuntu server.

Running the DB migration results in:

```
[1]    7379 segmentation fault  pipenv run flask db upgrade
```

I used `faulthandler` to try and get more context but it hasn't really helped, see output:

```
Current thread 0x000000010c0d8dc0 (most recent call first):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1043 in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 583 in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 670 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1035 in _handle_fromlist
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 118 in dbapi
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 87 in create
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 500 in create_engine
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 972 in create_engine
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 556 in get_engine
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 962 in get_engine
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 943 in engine
  File "migrations/env.py", line 29 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728 in exec_module
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 184 in load_module_py
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 98 in load_python_file
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 489 in run_env
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 298 in upgrade
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 271 in upgrade
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 96 in wrapped
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_migrate/cli.py", line 134 in upgrade
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610 in invoke
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 426 in decorator
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21 in new_func
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610 in invoke
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066 in invoke
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259 in invoke
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259 in invoke
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782 in main
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586 in main
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 967 in main
  File "/Users/ereeve/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-api-yqq7h-cT/bin/flask", line 8 in <module>
```

Has anyone seen similar?

Thanks

Comment: where is the exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the virtual env and everything fixed itself.